# Summing n numerical variables by grouping level specific to each

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, postgresql-9.1

I am working through a group by problem and could use some direction at this point. I want to summarize a number of variables by a grouping level which is different (but the same domain of values) for each of the variables to be summed. In pseudo-pseudo code, this is my issue: For each `empYEAR` variable (there are 20 or so employment-by-year variables in wide format), I want to sum it by the county in which the business was located in that particular year.

The data is a bunch of tables representing business establishments over a 20-year period from Dun & Bradstreet/NETS.

More details on the database, which is a number of flat files, all with the same primary key.

The primary key is `DUNSNUMBER`, which is present in several tables. There are tables detailing, for each year:

- employment
- county
- sales
- credit rating (and others)

all organized as follows (this table shows employment, but the other variables are similarly structured, with a year postfix).

```
dunsnumber|emp1990  |emp1991|emp1992|...    |emp2011|
a         | 12      |32     |31     |...    | 35    |
b         |         |2      |3      |...    | 5     |
c         | 1       |1      |       |...    |       |
d         | 40      |86     |104    |...    | 350   |
...
```

I would ultimately like to have a table that is structured like this:

```
county |emp1990|emp1991|emp1992|...|emp2011|sales1990|sales1991|sales1992|sales2011|...
A
B
C
...
```

My main challenge right now is this: How can I sum employment (or sales) by county by year as in the example table above, given that county as a grouping variable changes sometimes by the year and specified in another table?

It seems like something that would be fairly straightforward to do in, say, `R` with a long data format, but there are millions of records, so I prefer to keep the initial processing in postgres.

Comment: The table structure indeed looks like it has been designed for a statical package (such as SPSS, SAS, Splus, or R). Database people tend to normalise their data structure, such that repeating groups {emp1990,emp1991,...} are avoided (and instead are represented by an extra key-element). Please look up "normalisation" or "First normal Form".

Comment: I think you are right on that point--SAS might be better able to chew 6 million records than R, though. Do you think I should try to normalize the data from the format it was shipped in, or was that more of an FYI?

Comment: If you have access tot SAS it would be very easy, SAS's arrays are actually references to existing variables. And: DBMS's are not designed for statistics, you can aggregate some data into groups, create histograms, but crosstabulation is about the limit of feasability. For precomputing aggregate data sets SQL is very useful (even proc SQL in SAS ...) , but learning SQL (and data modeling) requires a paradigm shift in your thinking. and 6M records is not big for Postgres (or SAS). It might be too big for R, since R mostly requires the "working-set" to be present in core.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question this sounds relatively straight forward.  While I normally prefer normalized data to work with, I don't see that normalizing things beforehand will buy you anything specific here.

It seems to me you want something relatively simple like:

```
SELECT sum(emp1990), sum(emp1991), ....
  FROM county c
  JOIN emp e ON c.dunsnumber = e.dunsnumber
  JOIN sales s ON c.dunsnumber = s.dunsnumber
  JOIN ....
 GROUP BY c.name, c.state;
```

I don't see a simpler way of doing this.  Very likely you could query the system catalogs or information schema to generate a list of columns to sum up.  the rest is a straight group by and join process as far as I can tell.

if the variable changes by name, the best thing to do in my experience is to put together a location view based on that union and join against it. This lets you hide the complexity from your main queries and as long as you don't also join the underlying tables should perform quite well.

Comment: the problem is that the each year has a separate location variable that may or may not be different from preceding and following years. So I can't just use one variable in the 'GROUP BY' clause--the grouping level value should be looked up in a table to see the specific location for a specific year. I ultimately addressed it with a bunch of union queries to get to a long format, returning the location for each year.

Comment: if the variable changes by name, the best thing to do in my experience is to put together a location view based on that union and join against it.  This lets you hide the complexity from your main queries and as long as you don't also join the underlying tables should perform quite well.

Comment: I have added that to my answer.  I will say that I do a fiar bit of work with a poorly designed db where I have to do inline views for this sort of thing but have slowly been moving to standard defined views for code management reasons.